# What are the differences between Greinacher and Bridge voltage doublers?

Tags: rectifier, theory, voltage-doubler

I was reading a wiki article on [Voltage doublers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler#Voltage_doubling_rectifiers), and wondered - what are principal diffirences between two following schemes:

[image]

[image]

They all share same amount of components, but when and why should be one variant chosen over another?

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that in the first one, the output capacitor needs to be rated for the full output voltage. All of the other capacitors only need to carry half the output voltage.

Comment: So it's only about "capacitor rating" requirements? What do you think about circuit currents and coil/diodes operation?

Comment: What do *you* think about them? Perhaps you should try simulating both circuits. The simple simulator built into this site is perfectly adequate for this. What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Theoretically? Exactly as i stated in the question. Practically?.. To determine few typical applications for each, with small comment on "Why first may fit it better than second (or vice versa)". E.g. i'm looking for smth simple, like "first scheme is used for this this and this because of following properties. Second scheme Is typically found in that and that, for that reasons."